# PHP returning tripled results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I know what the script is doing and I think I understand why it is showing up 3 times, but I'm not sure how to fix it!

Here is the script as it stands:

```
$flagquery = "SELECT incident_flag FROM incident_attributes WHERE incident=2157"; 
$flagresult = mysqli_query($conn, $flagquery);
if (mysqli_num_rows($flagresult) > 0) {
while($firow = mysqli_fetch_array($flagresult)){ 

    foreach ($items as $flagrow) {
    $id = $flagrow['id'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($flagrow['name'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $form .= " <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>$name</label>
                    <div id='name-input-wrapper' class='col-sm-8 controls'>
                    <input type='checkbox' value='$id' name='flags[]' ";
    if ($firow["incident_flag"] == $id) $form .= 'checked';

    $form .= ">
                    </div>
                </div>";
    }
 }
}
echo $form;
```

Here is the related array

```
Array
(
[1] ( Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Bag
        [flag] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Screen
        [flag] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => HD
        [flag] => 0
    )

)
```

Here is the mysql DB incident_attributes

```
id incident incident_flag
1   2157    1
2   2157    2
3   2157    3
```

The whole goal of the script is to flag the box checked. Any other approaches to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You echo 3 checkbox for each result's row (3), so you have 9 checkboxes instead of 3.
You have to invert the two `foreach`, and to limit nested `foreach` to `checked` evaluation.

Since the query result become the nested `foreach`, you have to fetch rows before executing loops:

```
$firows = mysqli_fetch_all( $flagresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC );

foreach( $items as $flagrow ) 
{
    $id    = $flagrow['id'];
    $name  = htmlspecialchars( $flagrow['name'], ENT_QUOTES );

    $form .= " <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>$name</label>
                    <div id='name-input-wrapper' class='col-sm-8 controls'>
                    <input type='checkbox' value='$id' name='flags[]' ";
    foreach( $firows as $firow )
    {
        if( $firow["incident_flag"] == $id ) $form .= 'checked';
    }

    $form .= ">
                    </div>
                </div>";
}
```

As alternative (without nested `foreach`):

```
$firows = mysqli_fetch_all( $flagresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
$flags  = array_column( $firows, 'incident_flag' ); // $flags now is [ 1,2,3 ]

foreach( $items as $flagrow ) 
{
    (...)
    $form .= " <div class='form-group'> ... "
    if( in_array( $id, $flags ) ) $form .= 'checked';
    (...)
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank-You!